# An interior cone condition for Teichmuller spaces

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathcal{T}_{g,m}$ be the Teichmuller space of a compact oriented surface of genus $g$ with $m$ marked points. Consider it as a bounded domain in a complex space $\mathbb{C}^N$. Let $\xi$ be a point on the boundary of $\mathcal{T}_{g,m}$. Does the boundary of $\mathcal{T}_{g,m}$ satisfy an interior cone condition at $\xi$ ?

Recall that we say the boundary of $\mathcal{T}_{g,m}$ satisfies an interior cone condition at $\xi$ with parameters $r>0$ and $\theta \in (0,\pi/2]$ if there exists $v \in \mathbb{C}^N$ with $\lVert v \rVert =1$ such that
$$ \mathcal{C} (\xi,v,\theta,r) \subset \mathcal{T}_{g,m},$$
where
$$ \mathcal{C} (\xi,v,\theta,r):=\{z \in \mathbb{C}^N : 0<\lVert z-\xi \rVert<r, \angle(z-\xi,v) < \theta \}.$$

Comment: Do you mean the Bers embedding? Then the boundary is not even locally connected.

Comment: Yes, I mean the Bers embedding.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered, it is just a conjecture that the closure of the image of the Bers embedding (of a compact hyperbolic surface) is not locally connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many (most?) points of the boundary do not satisfy the interior cone condition.  See the paper [Spirals in the boundary of slices of quasi-Fuchsian space](https://www.ams.org/journals/ecgd/2006-10-08/S1088-4173-06-00133-0/) by Goodman.