# The boundary regularity of a Teichmüller domain

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, teichmuller-theory, several-complex-variables

By a Teichmüller domain, I mean the Bers embedding of a Teichmüller space (of a compact oriented surface of finite type) in a complex space.
It is known that the boundary of a Teichmüller domain is never of the class of $C^2$-smooth. What about the lower regularity?
For instance, do all Teichmüller domains have Lipschitz boundary?

Comment: Conjecurally, the boundary is not even locally connected.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - Is there a reference for that conjecture?  Or a paper that discusses related issues?  Thanks!

Comment: @Mahdi - This is not an answer to your question but perhaps is moving in the correct direction: the boundary of the Bers embedding is not $C^1$.  See the paper linked to here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/464087/an-interior-cone-condition-for-teichmuller-spaces/464106#464106

Comment: @Mahdi - what is your reference for the fact that the boundary is not $C^2$?

Comment: @SamNead: Ken Bromberg's paper where he proves that the boundary of the quasifuchsian space is not locally connected.

Comment: @SamNeed:  A paper by Subhojoy Gupta and Harish Seshadri entitled "On domains biholomorphic to Teichmüller spaces" has many interesting things.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06860  See also the reference [Yau11] in their paper.

Comment: @SamNead: Bromberg's paper is in Duke Math Journal, 2011.